# I can't use both "hover" and "outsideClick" triggers on Angular Bootstrap Tooltips

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui

I'm using Angular Bootstrap and want to have my tooltips trigger using a "hover" on desktop and "click" on mobile devices which can't hover but also have the tooltips close if you click outside the tooltip. I set it to **tooltip-trigger="hover outsideClick"** since "outsideClick" is now a supported trigger (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/tooltip/docs), however this breaks the tooltip completely so even the hover doesn't work.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" tooltip-trigger="hover outsideClick" uib-tooltip="Tooltip text here"></span>
```

Is there any way to make these work together?

If I just use **tooltip-trigger="hover click"** it's decent, but on mobile I can only close the tooltip by clicking the item again, versus being able to click elsewhere on the page to close it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `tooltip-trigger="mouseenter outsideClick"`? 
It seems like`hover` is not mentioned in the doc.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the `tooltip-trigger="hover focus"`, the `focus` will act as the `outsideClick`, closing the tooltip on the next click that the user makes. I've personally used this and it works great both for mobile and desktop.

It actually defaults to `hover focus` so you shouldn't even have to add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any chance you can use the native bootstrap library? As it supports what you are looking for by default.

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/6vn3kq36/) demonstrating this(please view it on your mobile device to see the tootlips working as expected)

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
});
```

You can read up on it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), as a side note, you have to manually enable the tooltip

> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, **meaning you must initialize them yourself.**
>
> One way to initialize all tooltips on a page would be to select them by their `data-toggle` attribute: